# how can i name it, values dimens folder for nexus 5?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-screen-support, android-screen

How to create different dimens values folder in android project to support all type of screens?

Answer (score -2):

[image: Check This Image],

Create different folders and create `dimens.xml`file in all folders.